# On top of nodejs boilerplate, install Angular

Tags: web-apps, javascript, web-development

I have a nodejs boilerplate with this files structure

```
bin
public/stylesheets
routes
views
.gitignore
app.js
package.json
```

when you run `$ npm start`, it should put the app to run on port `3000`.
Everything you put within `/public`, is what you will see in the first view when the app loads. I need to install Angular, but I don't want to do only like `$ npm install angular`, I want something like a kind of package with some predefined assets, like some views with routes and stuff like that, like a demo app to start working on. The problem is that every Angular generator I see on the internet, has his own node, and I have my node already.

Do you guys know any kind of angular package where I can get what I need?

Is just an angular app with some assets, without Node.

Answer (score 1):

yeoman has lot's of angular templates that are independent of server files.

http://yeoman.io/

```
npm install -g yo
cd public
yo angular
```